# What is the proper way to use an alternative binary

Tags: debian, binary, 7z, alternatives

I am on Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit.

I have these binaries of `7z` and their versions on my system:

```
/usr/bin/7z

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
```

and

```
/usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z/7z

7-Zip [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
```

As I am always using the latter, it is becoming increasingly annoying to write full path to it.

Shall I just define an `alias` or there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of replacing a binary with another in Debian such that it survives updates on the packages (for instance, replacing the init file of a BIND package), is doing a file diversion.

Basically a file diversion install/moves the original file to another location, and instructs the package manage system to place any subsequent install updates to that file in the new location, leaving untouched the original location.

As per the Debian [policy manual - diversions](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html), in your case:

```
dpkg-divert --divert /usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z/7z.old --rename /usr/bin/7z
cp /usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z/7z /usr/bin/7z
```

To remove the diversion:

```
dpkg-divert --remove /usr/bin/7z
```

Make backup copies of both the binaries before trying the diversion.

For more commands see: [Replace binaries and Files with dpkg-divert](http://www.debianadmin.com/replace-binaries-and-files-with-dpkg-divert.html)

Another easier alternative is holding the original package e.g. telling the package manager to not apply updates to it, and copying over the new binary as in:

```
echo "p7zip hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

or simplier:

```
apt-mark hold p7zip
```

See: [How to prevent a package from being updated in Debian](http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-prevent-a-package-from-being-updated-in-debian.html)

Another yet cleaner option would be building a deb with the new p7zip version, however as the method and specific steps vary with the packages, I won't try to describe it here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given by Rui F Ribeiro above, I would like to bring `update-alternatives` to the table. It is very handy to manage switching between the different binaries available for the same program.

First, check if the installed binary is an actual binary in `/usr/bin` or just a symlink. This can be done with `ls -la` for example:

```
$ ls -la $(which 7z)

# If it is a binary, it will look like this:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39 Aug 15  2016 /usr/bin/7z

# If a symlink, something like this:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Apr  9 12:58 /usr/bin/7z -> /some/another/path/7z
```

If you found a binary, move it away from its current location, using the `dpkg-divert` command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/7z.dist --rename /usr/bin/7z
```

Now you can use alternatives manager. The command has the following format:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>
```

Add both binaries to the `7z` alternatives group:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/7z 7z /usr/bin/7z.dist 10
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/7z 7z /usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z/7z 20
```

A symlink at `/usr/bin/7z` will be created, pointing to the binary with the highest priority of the list. If you need to switch between the binaries for any reason, just do this:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config 7z
```

An interactive prompt will ask you which binary to use:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative 7z (providing /usr/bin/7z).

  Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z/7z       20        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/7z.dist                        10        manual mode
  2            /usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z/7z       20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Type the `Selection` number you want and press enter. Done! The good thing about this approach is that applies system-wide and immediately, including all open shell sessions. There's no need to manipulate the `PATH`, also making it easier to switch back to the original binary whenever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your PATH environment variable to include specific directory of `7z`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/PeaZip/res/7z:$PATH
```

> > Is it possible to install `7z` in `/usr/local/bin` or link it into this directory?

Often, `/usr/local/lib` is before `/usr/bin` so the good binary will be found.

Comment: While it works, you should never put /usr/local or $HOME directories before the official directories in your $PATH due to security concerns.